# Set Content-Disposition header to media file

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-disposition, django-media

I work on an application that store media file on amazon S3. When I store them I rename it with a unique id but I would like to serve them with their original name. To rename files on download, amazon S3 let you set Content-Disposition header when you GET a resource or set Content-Disposition in objects' metadatas. My question is : how to perform it for media files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886828/set-content-disposition-in-aws-headers

Comment: No in this question I ask how to rename the file on GET request but in the previous it was on setting metadata on upload